# Using the UBT-12HC Serial Bus Motor with Arduino

Tags: serial, communication, servo, software

I recently bought [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Robot-Parts-Smart-Serial-Bus-Servo-High-Precision-Metal-Gear-Digital-Servo-Motor/373198301459?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20180816085401%26meid%3D62f08cbf6b2a40f8a4d936165bc091e1%26pid%3D100970%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D8%26mehot%3Dnone%26sd%3D143678350878%26itm%3D373198301459%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2380057.c100970.m5481&_trkparms=pageci%3A89814bc0-a15b-11eb-bb36-b601c6eccad0%7Cparentrq%3Aec2bfaf01780acf271bca688ffea18cd%7Ciid%3A1) motor and am trying to figure out how to use it. I also need a driver as this Bus Servo uses omnidirectional Serial communication. That is why I also bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073WRLJB2) TTL board.

- I, so far, have tried LewanSoul libraries and PC software, and many
  Python scripts with no success. They all just say that the incoming
  packet is invalid.
- I also tried Feetech's PC software and it picked up this motor as
  150 of them connected to the controller.
- I know the motor is responding because as soon as I unplug the
  motor, there is no response from any scripts and the Feetech tool
  detects nothing.

After researching, I found out that this motor is really similar to the "UBTECH Alpha Servos UBT-12HC". But they don't have much documentation on how to use them. I found tutorial [this](https://synthiam.com/Support/Skills/Servo/UBTECH-Alpha-Servos-UBT-12HC?id=16022) tutorial that shows you how to get it to work. There is a plugin for a program but I don't know how to use that program. So how do I use such a motor? Are there any steps I can take to figure out how to use it? Perhaps looking at the chips inside? Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find various libraries on GitHub - search for UBTech or Alpha-1 or UBT-12HC, or JIMU.  It looks like a very old UBT-12. Current versions have and internal color changing LED.   The protocol is 10 bytes long, starting with a header 0xFA 0xAF then the servo ID, then the command byte, then 4 data bytes, followed by a checksum, and a 0xED ender.  Don't try random commands, as you can easily brick the servo. Communication is 115200 baud, single wire, bi-directional.  I use an 74LS126 to drive it off any 3.3v controller, such as an arduino, raspberry pi or pico, etc.

```
 FA AF id cmd d0 d1 d2 d3 cksm ED

 example: move to position 90º ( range is 0 to 240 ) medium speed

 id   depends on the servo, can be 0 to 253
 cmd  0x01
 d0   angle  90 decimal is 0x5A hex
 d1   speed, in 20ms time chunks, 0 is fastest
 d2   0
 d3   save as d1. 
 cksm add bytes starting with id and ending with d3, modulus 256

 FA AF id 01 5A 25 0 25 ?? ED   # note: cksm depends on id
```

All UBTech servos use the same protocol.

Unfortunately it's getting difficult to find UBT-12HC servos, and the company isn't helpful with documentation.

Oh, and the board you bought is for a similar servo, the LX-15d or LX-16A (and others) made by LewanSoul or HiWonder.  DIFFERENT POWER PINS !!  and a different protocol.  Much better servos, still being made, and lots of documentation.  You can save yourself LOTS of trouble by just buying LX servos.

good luck!

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Wait, so you have one of these motors?